# How to get Id of Button that is clicked

Tags: javascript, button, target

I'm doing the rock-paper-scissors game with the freeCodeCamp video and can't get the id of a button that is clicked and Insert it into the Page.

```js
possibleChoices.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', (e){
   
        playerChoice = e.target.id
        playerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = playerChoice
    

}))
```

This is how they did it in the video but somehow for me it always says that playerChoice is equal to null. Does this mean that the e.target.id doesn't work?
I also wondered why they didn't put a function before the (e).
Thank you for answering!

Comment: Please, provide full example of code.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo: `(e){/*...*/}` is not a valid function — maybe you missed the arrow `=>` in `(e) => {/*...*/}`. Alternatively, you could write it as `function (e) {/*...*/}`

Comment: Do you have a nested element within the `<button>`? Because `e.target` will retrieve the element that triggered the function call (and the `click` event bubbles up through the DOM. Have you tried `e.currentTarget.id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
possibleChoices.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   
        playerChoice = e.target.id
        playerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = playerChoice
    

}))
```

you are writing e(){//..//..} which is invalid function, so you should write function e(){} or e=>{}

Comment: Okay, finally I saw the addition of the arrow (`=>`) to correct the typo; please: in your answer *explain* your answer, and what the problem was with the OP's code so that they can learn something useful from you.

Comment: Please only use code snippets for code that actually runs in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
    possibleChoices.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   
        playerChoice = e.target.id
        id = playerChoice.value
        playerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = playerChoice
    

}))
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.